# Encountering an Issue with `lang.astro` File Not Loading Correctly in an Astro Project for i18n Implementation

Tags: i18next, astrojs

**Question Description**:

I'm attempting to implement internationalization (i18n) in my Astro project but have encountered a problem where specific language files (e.g., `lang.astro`) are not loading correctly. My file structure may differ from typical Astro projects, which might be causing the issue.

**File Structure**:

My file structure is as follows:

```
- src
  - pages
    - about
      - index.astro
```

**Attempted Solution**:

To implement multilingual support, I tried adding language-specific Astro files under the relevant directory, like this:

```
- src
  - pages
    - about
      - index.astro
      - fr
        - index.astro
```

When I do this, I encounter an error that prevents the language file from loading correctly. I suspect this might be related to my file structure or how I'm adding the language files.

**Specific Questions**:

1. Are there specific file structure or configuration requirements for implementing i18n in Astro?
2. If my file structure differs from conventional practices, how should I correctly add and configure language files to avoid loading errors?

I'm puzzled about how to solve this problem and hope friends in the community can provide some guidance or suggestions. Thank you!